# ServerManager.OpenRemote(string serverName) throwing COM Class Error 800706cc in .NET core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a .NET Core Web Api project (3.0) and trying to get all the web sites from a remote server. To do this I am using **ServerManager.OpenRemote(string serverName)** from **Microsoft.Web.Administration (v6.1)** package which is throwing below error while accessing IIS web sites.

```
`Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine failed due to the following error: 800706cc`
```

Here is my method executing this functionality:

```
    using (ServerManager sm = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName.Trim()))
    {
        foreach (var site in sm.Sites) {
            string siteName = site.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If rebooting the server ,can the error be cleared?

Comment: Thank you Yivi. Yes, I already tried restarting the box and resetting the IIS also. No luck. I am not sure the kind of permissions the user needs on accessing IIS web sites. I am good with accessing windows services on that box without any problem